# Find out results of httpwebrequest POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, http-post, httprequest

Please refer to the below code.  How can I test/debug, whether the below code worked correctly or not. It runs and there are no compilation/runtime errors.

The end result of the below code is to set one of the controls in the page, to hold the POST data from below code. However I haven't come that far yet.

```
   protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{

    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    string postData = "http://s.com/is/image/scom/2Peel";
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

    // Prepare web request...
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://m.com/Confirm.aspx?ID=175");
    myRequest.Method = "POST";
    myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
    Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
    // Send the data.
    newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    newStream.Close();

}
```

**Update 1:** I tried to find out the response using below code, but the page doesn't load at all.

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

Console.WriteLine("Content length is {0}", response.ContentLength);
Console.WriteLine("Content type is {0}", response.ContentType);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [GetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) method of your HttpWebRequest object (which you named "myRequest").

Comment: HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse ();
            Console.WriteLine ("Content length is {0}", response.ContentLength);
            Console.WriteLine ("Content type is {0}", response.ContentType);             I tried to find out with above code, but the page didn't load at all even after I waited 10 mins.

Comment: That's odd... what page are you trying to access? Can you access it in a browser?